# Unable to Save Bcrypt Password in reset Password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am new in MEAN Stack, working on forgot password and reset password. i complete forgot password front end with Angular 8 and node and express. Mail sent to user email for reset password. but i am unable to save bcrypt password

Forget Password

```
exports.forgot_password= function(req, res){
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });
    },
    function(token, done) {
      User.findOne({ userEmail: req.body.userEmail }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          return res.json({status:false, message:'E-Mail not Found'})
        }
        console.log('step 1')
        user.reset_password_token = token;
        user.reset_password_expire = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        user.save(function(err) {
        done(err,token, user);
         });
      });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
        console.log('step 2')

      var smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
         service: 'Gmail',
         auth: {
          user: 'myemail',
          pass: 'mypass'
        }
      });
      console.log('step 3')

        smtpTrans.sendMail({
          from: 'myemail',
          to:user.userEmail,
          subject:'Password Reset',
          text:'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
            'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
            'angular URL + '/api/reset_password/' + token + '\n\n' +
            'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n',

        });
        console.log('Email Send');
}
  ], function(err) {
    console.log('this err' + ' ' + err)

  });
};
```

`Reset Password`

```
exports.resetpassword= function(req, res,next) {
async.waterfall([
  function(done){
    User.findOneAndUpdate({
      reset_password_token: req.body.token,
      reset_password_expire: {$gt: Date.now()}
    },function(err, user){
      if(user && !err){
        console.log('user')
        return res.json({status:true, message:'Reset Password'})
      }else{
        console.log('Token Expire');
        return res.json({status:false, message:'Token Invalid of Expire'})
      }
    },
      function(err, user,next){
        if (!user && err) {
          console.log('User Now found')
          return res.json({status:false, message:'User Not found'})
        }
        user.userPassword = req.body.userPassword;

        bcrypt.hash(req.body.userPassword,saltRounds,(hash)=> {
          user.userPassword = hash;

           })
        user.reset_password_token = undefined;
        user.reset_password_expire = undefined;
        console.log('password is '   + user.userPassword +   ' and the user is ' + user)

        //Save
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('here')
            return res.status(422).send({message: err});
            }else{
              console.log('here2')
              var smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'Gmail',
                auth: {
                  user: 'myemail',
                  pass: 'mypass'
                }
              });
              var data = {
                to: user.userEmail,
                from: 'myemail',
                subject: 'Password Reset Confirmation',
                text: 'Hello ' + user.userName +',\n\n' +
                ' - This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.userEmail + ' has just been changed.\n',
               };
              smtpTrans.sendMail(data, function(err) {
                console.log('Password has been changed')
                // req.flash('success', 'Success! Your password has been changed.');
                done(err);
            });
           }
        });
      });
    },
  ], function(err) {
    return res.json({status:true, message:'error'})
  });
};
```

`Schema`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema =  mongoose.Schema;

const User = new Schema({
  userName: String,
  userEmail: String,
  userPassword: {type: String,required: true, bcrypt: true},
  userConfPassword: String,
  userPhone: Number,
  userExperience: String,
  reset_password_token: String,
  reset_password_expire: Date,
});


const user = mongoose.model("user", User); //"user" is collections
module.exports= user;
```

Comment: Yes, but now i am facing another issue. i can't save my reset password in hash

Answer (score 0):

the issue mainly with this:

```js
bcrypt.hash(req.body.userPassword,saltRounds,(hash)=> {
          user.userPassword = hash;

})
```

and its async! try to replace it with:

```js
user.userPassword = bcrypt.hash(req.body.userPassword,saltRounds)
```

simple example:

```js
let x;

setTimeout(()=>{
  x = 400
  console.log(x) // 400
},200)

console.log(x) // undefined - this console.log while be executed first (js asynchronous concept)
```

Comment: i tried .but it showing error  events.js:186
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'userPassword' of null

Comment: the user value is null,check if the user is created

Comment: Thanks.. Yes, it is created. you can check the code as well

Comment: you see if the user object created it won't throw and error like this `Cannot set property 'userPassword' of null `, check pls and update us ^_^